# Magento 2 :: Creating and Customising home page

Tags: magento2, static-block

My client wants to have a custom editor so that they can edit or add images, videos blocks over homepage. What can be the best approach to do this?

He might need slider, special products slider, image blocks?
How to make it work as easy as it can ensuring all the aspect like the slider is from the different module, special product slider will be the widget and then image blocks. Some blocks can be disabled then they should get auto-managed.

The best way to achieve it?

Should I use static blocks and call them on home page?

Should I create different widgets?

Comment: I think you can use static blocks or update your homepage via xml layouts

Comment: If you want these all the flexibility then you should you static block.

Comment: Will it distort the design if any of the block is disabled?
How to manage it with different stores/ store views?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve that is use the  `Static and widget` combine.

- Create manage the Section of the homepage from Cms static block
- And set The position of those sections at home page via using Widget

*So if you using this solution, they if your client can disable a section of home page via In-active the CMS block or via delete that widget.*